# Not able to use the dd command to put an img file on USB stick

Tags: boot, usb, dd

I use this command to put an img file on an usb stick:

```
dd if=/home/jan/Downloads/COS/chromiumos_image.img of=/dev/usb/hiddev0 bs=4MB
dd: error writing '/dev/usb/hiddev0': Invalid argument
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
```

`hiddev0` is the name of the USB stick, visible in `/dev/usb`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Fdisk will tell you how your usb really identifies itself. Suppose it is /dev/sdc, continue running:

```
dd if=/home/jan/Downloads/COS/chromiumos_image.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4MB
```

*Change /dev/sdc to the one corresponding to your usb*